# Hiding a Categories content on just the Homepage 'Posts'?

Tags: categories

Is there a way I can hide a certain categories content from just the homepage Posts section of my Wordpress Site? So, those posts are still posted and live; just not visible nor accessible from the homepage posts area. I'm calling the category twice on the homepage; once in the header within a plugin I'm using, and the other where the posts are created by default by Wordpress. How can I hide my 'featured' category in the main page content of recent posts on the homepage?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "homepage"? Are you referring to the **Site Front Page** specifically, or to the **Blog Posts Index**, whether displayed on the Site Front Page or not?

Comment: Thanks for the response; I'm not sure the exact name of the area. But looking at; http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentyten The old twenty ten theme. The main wider area on the left, that populates with posts as you create them. I just want to prevent a certain category from appearing there. But I want them to still exist, just not displaying there.

Comment: Sure... but *in what context* do you want to do this? Always? Only on the site front page? Some other context?

Comment: I'm using a header/slider plug-in that calls that category to populate it; it's setup that the header links to those posts within said category. I want this to remain in tact across the site's header; I just don't want the category to be present anywhere else without accessing the links within my header plug-in to get there.

Comment: Does the slider always appear in the header, or only on the front page?

Comment: It will just need to appear on the front page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it sounds like you'll want to modify the primary Loop using [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), but only on the **Site Front Page**.

I don't think TwentyTen includes a `front-page.php` template file, so we'll modify `index.php` directly. Add the following code to `index.php`, anywhere *before the Loop output*:

```
<?php
// Determine if we're on the site Front Page
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    // Globalize $wp_query
    global $wp_query;
    // Create argument array in which we 
    // exclude desired category IDs. Categories
    // are listed as a comma-separated string.
    // e.g. '-3', or '-1,-2,-3'
    $exclude_cats = array( 'cat' => '-3' );
    // Merge custom arguments with default query args array
    $custom_query_args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, $exclude_cats );
    // Query posts using our modified argument array
    query_posts( $custom_query_args );
} // is_front_page()
?>
```